# Pandas: Combine category-based heat map with values-based heatmap?

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

I'm trying to have a heatmap where each of the 5 categories (x axis) has its own overall color and the value for each month determines how light or dark that square is. I've been using sns.heatmap for the plot below but I'm open to other Python-based options. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to do that?

[image: category by month]

I've used the following code and with cmap="Greys" I can see how the value of each square varies, but each vertical column should ideally be a different overall preset color. Note I'm not looking for any additional squares.

```
sns.heatmap(viewed, linewidth=.5, cmap="Greys", fmt="d")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can loop through the columns and use each one as a mask. To have consistent dark/light squares, one `norm` can be calculated for the full set.

An independent colorbar could be created by combining the norm with a grey colormap.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.cm import ScalarMappable
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

viewed = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 5) * 18 + 12, columns=[*'abcde'], index=range(1, 11))
viewed_np = viewed.to_numpy()
norm = plt.Normalize(viewed_np.min(), viewed_np.max())

cmaps = ['Reds', 'Blues', 'Oranges', 'Purples', 'Greens']

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for col in range(len(viewed.columns)):
    mask = np.ones_like(viewed_np)
    mask[:, col] = 0
    sns.heatmap(viewed, mask=mask, linewidth=.5, cmap=cmaps[col], norm=norm, cbar=False, ax=ax)
ax.tick_params(axis='y', rotation=0)
fig.colorbar(ScalarMappable(cmap='Greys', norm=norm), ax=ax)
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: seaborn heatmap with different cmap per column]

To indicate specific colors instead of the predefined colormaps, a `LinearSegmentedColormap` can be created between white and a given color:

```
colors = ['darkred', 'darkblue', 'saddlebrown', 'darkgreen', 'darkorchid']
for col, color in zip(range(len(viewed.columns)), colors):
    mask = np.ones_like(viewed_np)
    mask[:, col] = 0
    sns.heatmap(viewed, mask=mask, linewidth=.5, cmap=LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('', ['white', color]),
                norm=norm, cbar=False, ax=ax)
```

Comment: Great suggestion, JohanC - the LinearSegmentedColormap option did the trick.

Answer (score 4):

Below is an implementation using `matplotlib`.

[image]

Data for testing:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Test data
data = np.random.randn(12, 5) * 0.1 + np.arange(12).reshape(-1, 1) / 25

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=[f'Category {i}' for i in range(5)])
df['Month'] = pd.date_range(start='2023-01', freq='M', periods=12).month_name()
```

[image]

Create heatmap:

```
#Specify the y axis column
y_column = 'Month'

#
#Plot the dataframe "df"
#
sequential_cmaps =  [
    'Greys', 'Purples', 'Blues', 'Greens', 'Oranges', 'Reds',
    'YlOrBr', 'YlOrRd', 'OrRd', 'PuRd', 'RdPu', 'BuPu',
    'GnBu', 'PuBu', 'YlGnBu', 'PuBuGn', 'BuGn', 'YlGn',
    'Greys_r', 'Purples_r', 'Blues_r', 'Greens_r', 'Oranges_r', 'Reds_r',
    'YlOrBr_r', 'YlOrRd_r', 'OrRd_r', 'PuRd_r', 'RdPu_r', 'BuPu_r',
    'GnBu_r', 'PuBu_r', 'YlGnBu_r', 'PuBuGn_r', 'BuGn_r', 'YlGn_r',
]

x_columns = df.columns.drop(y_column)

#Adjust colour scales
# Prevents light colours washing out
adjust_colour_vmin = 1.2
adjust_colour_vmax = 1
backgnd_colour = 'white'

f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(len(x_columns), len(df)))
for x, column in enumerate(x_columns):
    values = df[column]
    ax.scatter(
        [x] * len(df),
        range(0, len(df)),
        c=values,
        cmap=plt.get_cmap(sequential_cmaps[x % len(sequential_cmaps)]),
        edgecolors=backgnd_colour,
        linewidths=2,
        vmin=values.min() * adjust_colour_vmin,
        vmax=values.max() * adjust_colour_vmax,
        marker='s',
        s=2900
    )

ax.set_facecolor(backgnd_colour)

#Axis labels
ax.set_xticks(range(0, len(df.columns) - 1))
ax.set_xticklabels(x_columns, rotation=45, fontsize=10)

ax.set_yticks(range(0, len(df)))
ax.set_yticklabels(df[y_column], rotation=30)

#Limits
ax.set_xlim(ax.axis()[0] - 0.5, ax.axis()[1] + 0.5)
ax.set_ylim(ax.axis()[2] - 0.1, ax.axis()[3] + 0.1)

#Spines
[ax.spines[spine].set_visible(False) for spine in ['left', 'right', 'bottom', 'top']]
```